# Generic Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

Working generally I get a `PropertyInfo` method a property, this property will always be a

`Dictionary<someobject, customenum>` and I need through this property that I could know what type of key (someobject) ...

can anyone help me?

sorry for english is not my native language!

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't enough information here for us to understand what you need help with. Do you have the code that you're having trouble with? If so, put it up here and identify where you're struggling.

Comment: Please provide more info. This doesnt give us enough info to help you out.

Comment: so you have a property and you want through reflection to know the type of the keys and values?

Comment: Though it's hard to decipher, I believe what he's asking is how to determine the data type of the key in a Dictionary<>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var arguments = d.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
var keyType = arguments[0];
var valueType = arguments[1];
```

Comment: hehehe sorry everyone for not being able explain it ... but this(d.GetType().GetGenericArguments();) is exactly what I needed thanks!